# How can I make HTTrack only download files on the current domain?

Tags: http, download, httrack

No matter how hard I try, I can't seem to get httrack to leave links going to other domains intact. I've tried using the `--stay-on-same-domain` argument, and that doesn't seem to do it. I've also tried adding a filter doesn't do it.

There simply *must* be some option I'm missing here.

Answer (score 15):

Setting the option "Maximum external depth" to `0` did not work , even though it should be expected.

What works:

Go to > Options > Scan Rules and enter in the text field (extra line): `-* +*yourdomain.com/*`

Here are more settings to learn about: [HTTrack: How to download folders only from a certain subfolder level?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36244419/1066234)

Comment: How frustrating to have to manually specify the domain in the scan rules each time. ‍♂️ It should really detect that.

Comment: When I did this it reduced the number of pages downloaded from other domains - but strangely not to zero. Some pages were still downloaded from other domains.

Answer (score 1):

Set maximum external depth to 0. In the GUI that this can be found here:

[image]

If you are using the command line version, the option is

```
%e0
```

[Note: not an expert on HTTRACK, so please correct if necessary]

Comment: This doesn't always work. I have my settings the same as your screenshot and yet I also get many many pages from Wikipedia. 

Answer (score -2):

In "Set Option" > "Limits", try

`Maximum mirroring depth = 1` (Keep this 2, when 1 doesn't work)

And

`Maximum external depth = 0`

Worked for me!!