# HTTrack: How to download folders only from a certain subfolder level?

Tags: httrack

HTTrack gives [filter options](https://www.httrack.com/html/filters.html) but I cannot figure out how to download a certain subfolder **level** and ignore all other subfolders.

Example:

```
domain.com/
domain.com/pets/
domain.com/pets/elephant
domain.com/zoo/tiger
domain.com/pics/giraffe
domain.com/pics/giraffe/details
```

I would like to only download the subfolders `elephant`, `tiger` and `giraffe` as HTML including images linked from there.

Is HTTrack that powerful? (I am using the Windows GUI version "WinHTTrack".)

PS: It would be nice to have this as a program option, e.g. "Minimum mirroring depth".

Answer (score 6):

I found a way how to do it:

```
-*
-domain.com/*[path]/*
-domain.com/*[path]
+domain.com/*[path]/*[path]/*
-domain.com/*/specialfolder*
+domain.com/*specialimages*.jpg
-mime:*/* +mime:text/html +mime:image/*
```

Only issue: To get all URLs it was not enough to specify the root domain but also the first level subfolders (for the example: domain.com/pets, domain.com/zoo, domain.com/pics).